# android - i'm getting has leaked window that was originally added here error, please help ..dont know what to do

Tags: android

Im getting this err. msg: " has leaked window that was originally added here ".
I have this code:

ball.java:

```
    ...


  if(current_ball.physx.position.distance2(renderer.gPlayer.physx.position) <= (graphics.SQUARE_SIZE-4)*2)

            {
                if(renderer.gSnd_GameOver!=0 && renderer.bUseSound) renderer.gSndPool.play(renderer.gSnd_GameOver, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                renderer.bIsGameOver = true;

                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = newgame.STATE_GAMEOVER;
                newgame.handler.sendMessage(msg);
                return;
            }
```

next,
in newgame.java ACTIVITY i have:

```
    static DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new  
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        Intent intent = null;

        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

            dialog.dismiss();
            ((Activity) newgame.gNewGameContext).finish();
            intent = new Intent ( newgame.gNewGameContext , newgame.class );
            newgame.gNewGameContext.startActivity( intent );
            Log.d("redwing", "YES button ... successfuly processed, new intent starded.");

            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:


            dialog.dismiss();
            ((Activity) newgame.gNewGameContext).finish();
            Log.d("redwing", "NO button ... successfuly processed, current intent was closed.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

and this HANDLER wich receives messages when GameOver (message is generated in ball.java as mentioned in above code) ... and instantiates a new alert dialog with this question "PlayAgain?" (note that this HANDLER exists and it's created in newgame.java) :

```
    public static Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);


        switch(msg.what)
        {
            case newgame.STATE_GAMEOVER:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(newgame.gNewGameContext);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("GaMeOvEr");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setMessage("Play again ?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                                                    .setNegativeButton("No" , dialogClickListener).show();
             break;
        }

    }  
};
```

...also "newgame.gNewGameContext" is set like this in newgame.java (in onCreate) :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle newgameInstance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(newgameInstance);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    gNewGameContext = this;
    ......
```

To review, i do this:

1. when gameover=true, i send a message to the Handler.
2. the Handler receives gameover msg. and instantiates a new alert box
3. if user presses No button in this alert box i get "has leaked window that
   was originally added here"  Error ! :(

Please help, i dont know how to fix this. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for this might be because you are trying to finish the activity where you have created a Dialog even before closing the dialog.So obviously since your dialog won't have any reference to the activity which actually created it, this problem arises. Consider changing your code in such a way it is handled.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  As you can see in my code, i do a :  " dialog.dismiss(); ((Activity) newgame.gNewGameContext).finish();  "  So i dismiss the Alert Before the Activity shutdown. Where do i go wrong ?

Comment: Pleasseee help me , any ideeas ??
I'm stuck with this since more than a week ... :(

Comment: so u r saying that this error occurs only during negative button being pressed. So did u try removing finish() in the negative button and see? I mean only try to dismiss the dialog there. just check if it crashes or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i really appreciate that!                   I'll try what you said in ~ 5 hours (now im at work)  and i'll come back with an answer.  But meanwhile, do you find something  done wrong so far in my above code  ??

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... It seems to work now, at least so far.

I've just made few runs (10-20 runs) of the app. and results are good (i.e. no crashing)

I've cleared the queued messages in the Handler when GameOver=true , here is the code with the changes (maybe it will help others) :

```
    public static Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);


        switch(msg.what)
        {
            case newgame.STATE_GAMEOVER:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(newgame.gNewGameContext);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("GaMeOvEr");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setMessage("Play again ?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                                                    .setNegativeButton("No" , dialogClickListener).show();
                this.removeMessages(newgame.STATE_GAMEOVER);
             break;
        }


    }  
};
```

.. i've added this line of code (clear the message queue in Handler):
"this.removeMessages(newgame.STATE_GAMEOVER);"

Dont know if this is the solution, but it works so far.
Thank you again.

Ok, another thing i've noticed is this:

I have an application installed on my phone, something like TaskManager. With this application i can see how much memory my app. uses, CPU , etc. (monitoring apps)
But when I exit my Game app., and run TaskManager i noticed that my app. is still running but in "sleep" mode. Is this normally ?

Thanks.